# How can I prepend each block of text with an ascending letter of the alphabet?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I have text in a text area with string in the form of question, followed by answer in the following format:

```
THIS IS A QUESTION
- This is the 1st answer

THIS IS ANOTHER QUESTION
- This is another answer

HERE IS THE FINAL QUESTIONS
- Oh boy we are done!
```

I'd like to give the user the option of outputting the transcript of question and answers with an ascending order of letters prepended to the question line as follows:

```
A. THIS IS A QUESTION
- This is the 1st answer

B. THIS IS ANOTHER QUESTION
- This is another answer

C. HERE IS THE FINAL QUESTIONS
- Oh boy we are done!
```

I'm not experienced with javascript regex, but I got as far as

> (/.*[\s]/gm)

But it's not quite working in capturing the group inbetween the empty line, nor can I figure out how to loop through my array of capital letters and add them once matched.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a replacer function that keeps track of the character code most recently replaced with - start with 64 (65 corresponds to A, 66 corresponds to B, etc).

For the regex itself, just match the beginning of a line followed by a word character - so, a word boundary:

```js
const str = `THIS IS A QUESTION
- This is the 1st answer

THIS IS ANOTHER QUESTION
- This is another answer

HERE IS THE FINAL QUESTIONS
- Oh boy we are done!`;

let lastCharCode = 64;

const result = str.replace(/^\b/gm, () => String.fromCharCode(++lastCharCode) + '. ');
console.log(result);
```